# If a champion jumps over Volibear (like Tristana or Corki) and the bear uses Majestic Roar when they are on top, does the slow proc?

Tags: league-of-legends

I mean, different from other abilities is a ROAR, so I'd say it should, but I wonder if that was implemented in the game.

Comment: It should slow them unless it specifically says that they are untargetable during the jump.

Comment: and if it's not a blink/teleport. (i.e. Katarina during shunpo would not be affected since it's a blink) However, Jax during his Jump (Q) would be affected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the champion would still be affected by it. During dashes like the ones of these Champions the caster is **targetable** during the whole "flight". Targetable really is the key word here. Champions like Master Yi or Maokai won't be affected by it during their dashes.

The Roar is basically just an AoE spell around Volibear but you can basically hit every spell if you're fast and skilled enough. It's even possible to Autoattack a Dashing champion mid-air as long as he's targetable.

Answer (score -1):

These abilities are a type of forced movement, and not blinks (such as Ezreal or Katarina), and are still affected by abilities such as Volibear's Majestic Roar